# website not getting update even after firebase deploy

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have made a portfolio website and deployed it using firebase but whenever I update/upload something new to it. Using

```
firebase deploy
```

Nothing gets changed. In the Firebase dashboard, the versions getting updated but not the actual website

[github repo of the website](https://github.com/itsAfnanAlam/portfolio-website)

[My website link](https://mohd-afnan-alam.web.app/)

Comment: Dumb question: Did you build the project before deploying? I actually forgot it one time and also searched for reasons that there is no update. :D
Your build script in package.json seems a bit off. I'd say you only need this:
`"build": "react-scripts build && firebase deploy",`

Comment: Nice website btw :)

Comment: @sandrooco  nothing changed : /

Comment: Hey did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @sandrooco still searching for one...

Comment: Have you tried clearing caches?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem
turns out i had caching enabled in my chrome browser
to undo this, i opened dev tools, then i went to network tab and checked Disable cache
and it worked !

Answer (score -1):

I have same isue with React Vite project.
To fix that problem do this:

1.Build you're app.

```
npm run build
```

or if you using yarn

```
yarn run dev
```

2.`firebase deploy` again.

```
firebase deploy
```

3.clear all you're browser history and cache.
[chrome://history/](https://chrome://history/)

I hope this can fix the bug!